# "Unable to load libuv" while installing PHP driver extension for Cassandra on Centos 7.1

Tags: cassandra, datastax-php-driver

```
checking for uv_version in -luv... no
configure: error: Unable to load libuv
ERROR: `/var/tmp/cassandra/configure' failed
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the console output as text, not as an image - this way other users aren't able to find this question if they have similar problems. Please also add detailed informations what steps you've made until this happend. Even obvious and correct preparation steps may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS packages, libuv are not yet available in a repo for CentOS 7.
( The pramberger.repo has libuv for CentOS 5, CentOS 6 ).

It's easy to build CentOS 7 packages from the Fedora 22 SRPM, libuv-1.4.0-1.fc22.src.rpm 
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/22/Everything/source/SRPMS/l/libuv-1.4.0-1.fc22.src.rpm

```
$ rpmbuild -bb libuv.spec
```

.. Or you can use my result, { libuv-1.4.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm, libuv-devel-1.4.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm, libuv-static-1.4.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm }.

All three packages in one tar file "libuv-1.4.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.tar" : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTUlwOTFTQkJ1V28/view?usp=sharing

Installing the libuv packages : 1) `$ cd libuv-1.4.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64/`

2) `# yum install *.rpm`

[libuv](/questions/tagged/libuv)

Comment: Now getting this error with rpmbuild "error: Failed build dependencies: libtool is needed by libuv-1:1.4.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64" And no effect with your result same result.

Comment: ? No libtool ? Then please do : # yum install libtool

Comment: But why not use the 'libuv' packages you can download ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTUlwOTFTQkJ1V28/view?usp=sharing